# APK creation date

Tags: android, date, apk, creation

Is it possible to locate the actual date an Android application was created? I have various APKs that have been reverse engineered so the source code is available to view as is the AndroidManifest. The only date I currently have is the modified date via each one's properties in Linux.

Comment: Try with `PackageManager.getPackageInfo` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
String mVersion = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
    "com.yourapppackage", 0).versionName;
```

Cheers

Comment: thanks. actually gone down a much simpler route (hope it's correct) by just unzipping original apk and using long listing in linux to see date. seems to be correct for now..